# Lollipop Hide Navigation Bar and Controls Permanently

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, kiosk-mode

1. I am using following code to implement Kiosk mode and getting this as default when I run my app for the very first time

   ```
   public class KioskActivity extends Activity {

   final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
           | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

       getActionBar().hide();

       setContentView(wenchao.kiosk.R.layout.activity_lock_activity);
       DevicePolicyManager myDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
       ComponentName mDPM = new ComponentName(this, MyAdmin.class);
       if (myDevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(this.getPackageName())) {
           String[] packages = {this.getPackageName()};
           startLockTask();
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not owner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       setVolumMax();

       Button lock_btn = (Button)findViewById(wenchao.kiosk.R.id.lock_button);
       Button unlock_btn = (Button)findViewById(wenchao.kiosk.R.id.unlock_button);
       Button appButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.appButton);

       lock_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               startLockTask();
               return false;
           }
       });

       unlock_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               stopLockTask();
               return false;
           }
       });

       appButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                ......
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Volume button is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
       }

       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Volume button is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
       }

       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }

   private void setVolumMax(){
       AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
       am.setStreamVolume(
               AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,
               am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM),
               0);
   }
   }
   ```

   [image]

   It looks just perfect to me, I thought I achieved what I wanted.
2. Here comes the pain point, when I swipe down from the top, getting transparent bar with controls, I was not assuming this:

   [image]

   Actually it comes for few seconds and then disappears (but I don't want it to appear within my app, even for a millisecond)
3. When I move to some other app, using tap on App button, and then come back to my app, getting this, its annoying:

   [image]

   Whenever it comes never disappears, there is no option except closing the app, to get rid of

   values > styles.xml:

   ```
   <resources>

       <!-- Base application theme. -->
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       </style>

   </resources>
   ```

   values-v21 > styles.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you cannot stop it appearing when you swipe down from the top since that's the only way to exit an app if it misbehaves.

Comment: There's no way to remove it permanently without modifying the operating system and running your own build of Android.